# How to check whole website for certain conditions in rendered source of every page , automatically?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, xhtml, automated-tests, testing-strategies

Like I want to check

on Every page `<h3>` tag must come after `<h2>` otherwise page should be marked.

like if any page has PDF then Some particular text `<p>Download Adobe reader from here</p>` should be at bottom of every page is this condition is not matched then page should be marked.

I want to make different type of conditions to check then want to check on whole site and if anything mismatch then report should be generated.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Do you necessarily have to use XHTML?</del>  I'd use Python and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), myself.

(**Edit:** I was confused - I was thinking of XSLT, not XHTML, and I thought "why would you use XSLT for someting like this?".  XHTML is fine, and my recommendation of Python and BeautifulSoup still stands.)

Comment: can u give some more info how can i make and run test ?

Answer (score 0):

This ruby gem looks like it could be useful to you:

http://code.google.com/p/opticon/

I haven't personally used it, but it claims to basically do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've had, and still have, the same need on many of my projects. In my case I'm looking for anything with the class 'error'. This is supported by the [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) product in it's verification engine.

In my case, as a quick example, I have several "Web" states and my generic verify script is:

CheckNot //div[@class='error']

Now the way TestPlan works is that every state within "Web" will first run this generic verify script.

If you're interested I could help you come up with the exact syntax needed to do your check.